# XML Transform with XSLT

Tags: xslt-2.0

I have a XML file like below:

```
<NOP>A focus on individual exhibitors is essential, though, in order to 
  understand how these figures influenced American (and global) culture and 
  how audiences were attracted to movies and movie theaters. Charles Musser 
  writes in his examination of Lyman Howeâ€™s career that â€œa focus on 
  exhibition lends itself to industrial history precisely because it must 
  address the economic basis of the motion picture industryâ€”the showmanâ€™s 
  ability to bring patrons through the front door.â€<ENREF>1</ENREF> In order 
  to understand the artistic and managerial influences of showmen like Samuel 
  Lionel Rothafel (â€œRoxyâ€) and Sidney Patrick Grauman, one must analyze 
  their construction of stardom, their ethnic heritage and cultural background, 
  their facility with music, theater, film, and other performing arts, and the 
  ways in which they motivated patrons to enter their â€œfront door.â€
</NOP>
```

and I'm using the below XSLT with XML spy but it's not working for 'ENREF'. Any help

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:template match="NOP">
  <div class="no-indent"><span><xsl:value-of select="."/></span></div>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="ENREF">
    <small>
    <sup>
     <xsl:element name="a">
      <xsl:attribute name="id">enref-<xsl:value-of select="."/></xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:attribute name="href">#fn<xsl:value-of select="."/></xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
     </xsl:element>
    </sup>
    </small>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Your XML document is almost impossible to read. Please, edit and add new lines (if they wouldn't affect the problem (which I believe is so). At present, it is virtually impossible to find any `ENREF` element.

Answer (score 1):

It does not suffice to write a template matching a certain element, you also need to ensure the element is processed. You have not shown us the result you want so I have to guess what you want to achieve but for a start try changing

```
  <xsl:template match="NOP">
  <div class="no-indent"><span><xsl:value-of select="."/></span></div>
  </xsl:template>
```

to

```
  <xsl:template match="NOP">
  <div class="no-indent"><span><xsl:apply-templates/></span></div>
  </xsl:template>
```

That way the child nodes of the `NOP` element are processed, either by the built-in templates (which ensure with `<xsl:apply-templates/>` that the processing is kept up for grandchildren and further descendants) or by your templates (like the one for the `ENREF` element).

Comment: If Martin Honnen's answer solves your problem, you should indicate that by clicking on the checkmark that appears next to it in your interface.  (See the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask) for more detailed instructions if you need them.)